# Upload Larget File Azure Blob .net SDK v12 Problem

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, storage

I am trying to large file to Azure Blob using .net SDK V12. This program can upload small files, without exception, But larget file threw exception. Do you have a solution of this problem.

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(uploadFileName);

using (FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
{
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
    var meta = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    meta["LastWriteTime"] = new FileInfo(localFilePath).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    meta["CreationTime"] = new FileInfo(localFilePath).CreationTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    await blobClient.SetMetadataAsync(meta);
}
```

I want to know not the solution of using .NET SDK V11, but V12.

This exception is as follows and the file size is 91.6MB

```
System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.)
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1[TWriteAdapter](ValueTask writeTask, Byte[] bufferToReturn)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncChunked[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TWriteAdapter](TWriteAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.WriteToAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
```

Comment: how about you start by sharing the exception?!

Comment: What's the size of your file? I upload the file(about 443.53 MiB) success with `using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                await blob.UploadAsync(file);
            }`.

Comment: @silent Thank you for your comment.I added the exception.

Comment: @PamelaPeng Thank you for your comment. The File size is 91.6MB.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when using `StorageConnectionString`, like this:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(StorageConnectionString);
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(BlobContainerName);
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(BlobName);

// Open the file and upload its data
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    await blob.UploadAsync(file);
}
```

I changed to use `StorageSharedKeyCredential`, it worked.

```
string accountName = "";
string accountKey = "";
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/");

// Create a SharedKeyCredential that we can use to authenticate
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

// Create a client that can authenticate with a connection string
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(serviceUri, credential);

// BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(StorageConnectionString);
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(BlobContainerName);
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(BlobName);

// Open the file and upload its data
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    await blob.UploadAsync(file);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'll try this. If you know, do you know why using StorageConnectionString is working ?I want to know the reason.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why. I tried the two methods with the latest version of storage SDK, the first one threw the error but the second one succeeded.